# shortcut keys, specifically alt key in a dialog WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new in WPF, I'm trying to close a dialog pressing Alt+A.
I opended the dialog pressing a button in the main window, but I want to close it pressing the button Annulla, which is not defined in MainViewModel but it is defined in another ViewModel.

I tried to put my XAML in Keybinding in the Window inputBindings instead of the Grid, but it gives an error, "The type 'InputBindings' was not found in Dialog:CustomDialog.
I tried to put it in MainWindow XAML, where I press the button that open the dialog, but is does not work.

In my dialog XAML

```
                <KeyBinding Key="A" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{Binding Path=BtnAnnullaMassivi}" />
            </Grid.InputBindings>
```

In the other ViewModel

private ICommand _BtnAnnullaMassivi;

```
    public ICommand BtnAnnullaMassivi
    {
        get
        {
            if (_BtnAnnullaMassivi == null)
            {
                _BtnAnnullaMassivi = new USCommands(
                    item =>
                    {
                        //per chiudere la dialog                         
                        Cancel = false;
                        _closeCommand.Execute(this);
                    });
            }
            return _BtnAnnullaMassivi;
        }
```

Pressing Alt+A it does not work.
Suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: Did you try putting the Keybinding in the Window inputBindings instead of the Grid?

Comment: @Jeff R. I've already tried, but it does not work